# Can we integrate Web RTC for Video calling without using of any third party service provider in my app?

Tags: android

I want to integrate Video calling in my android application using of Web RTC. Is there any option that we can use Web RTC directly without help of any third party service providers like Pubnub, tokbox, Quickblox etc.?

Comment: No. i just want to confirm that which one would be good to integrate. is there any option for WebView?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [AndroidRTC](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC). It can be used for creating video chatting applications natively in Android.